# the error when i change a number in decimal base to another base

Tags: java

I am writing a java code to **Change a number from decimal base to another base**.
But I don't know why the program runs wrong. I think the error comes from function Prin_as. Can anyone tell me why ?

Below is my code,

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class bai2chuyendoi {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a, b;

        System.out.println("Number in decimal base:");
        a = Enter();
        System.out.println("Other base :");
        b = Enter();
        Change_base (a, b);
    }

    public static int Enter() {
        int n = 0;
        boolean check = false;
        while (!check) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            try {
                n = sc.nextInt();
                check = true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Enter again:");
                sc.nextLine();
            }
        }
        return n;
    }

    public static void Change_base(int a, int b) {
        int i = 0;
        int[] c = new int[8];
        while (a != 0) {
            c[i] = a % b;
            a = a / b;
            i++;

        }
        while (i >= 0) {
            --i;
            if (c[i] < 10) {
                System.out.print(c[i]);
            } else {
               System.out.print((char) (c[i] + 55));
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error? and where? the stack trace will lead you to the exact line.

Comment: You can debug your code and update your question with errors you face.

Comment: Where is the function `Prin_as`?

Answer (score 0):

The error was in *Change_base* method in second while loop.
You need decrement 'i' and check that i >= 0, but you didn't.

```
while (--i >= 0) {
      if (c[i] < 10) {
          System.out.print(c[i]);
      } else {
          System.out.print((char) (c[i] + 55));
      }
}
```